# Android grid layout with different cell sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I've been doing so research but I cannot find a way to do a grid layout  with different cell  sizes.

Below there is an image of what I am trying to do highlighted in yellow.

[grid that I am trying to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR5yG.jpg)

Comment: For hash tags u dont need to use grid. There are so many libraries for hash tags. Check on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **FourSquare collection picker**( https://github.com/anton46/Foursquare-CollectionPicker),
it look like this :-

[image]